# Checking to see if ofstream is empty?

Tags: c++, stream, ofstream

I've created an ofstream and there is a point in which I need to check if it's empty or has had things streamed into it.

Any ideas how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Cant you check it with eof or rdstate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::ofstream` files don't support this directly. What you can do if this is an important requirement is to create a filtering stream buffer which internally used `std::filebuf` but also records if there was any output being done. This could look look as simple as this:

```
struct statusbuf:
    std::streambuf {
    statusbuf(std::streambuf* buf): buf_(buf), had_output_(false) {}
    bool had_output() const { return this->had_output_; }
private:
     int overflow(int c) {
         if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof())) {
             this->had_output_ = true;
         }
         return this->buf_->overflow(c);
     }
     std::streambuf* buf_;
     bool            had_output_;
};
```

You can initialize an `std::ostream` with this and query the stream buffer as needed:

```
std::ofstream out("some file");
statusbuf     buf(out.rdbuf());
std::ostream  sout(&buf);

std::cout << "had_output: " << buf.had_output() << "\n";
sout << "Hello, world!\n";
std::cout << "had_ouptut: " << buf.had_output() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use [ofstream.rdbuff](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/rdbuf/) to get the file buffer and than use [streambuf::sgetn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/sgetn/) to read it. I believe that should work.

Comment: No, it won't work: the read buffer of a stream buffer currently writing is typically not filled. The two buffers don't have anything to do with each other and they aren't keep in sync.

Comment: Sure, give it a go. However, even if there is on standard library implementation that does it or even a majority of implementations which does it, the way to determine whether this works is to read the standard. I'm pretty sure the standard doesn't guarantee this and the implementation I have done certainly doesn't keep the two buffers in sync.